# How to add additional keys to a dictionary in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I wondering how you could add an additional key value pair to an already existing tcl dictionay. For example:.

```
dict set greetings english Hi
$greetings add key_pair German Hallo
```

Comment: Er, you're already doing it in the first line of that snippet...

Comment: The [`dict`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just described *exactly* what `dict set` does. Several other `dict` subcommands also do that.

However, note that you are logically reading the dictionary out of the variable, creating a new dictionary from it with the new key in it, and writing the new dictionary back to the variable. (The implementation is more efficient than that, but the model is definitely read/create-new/write.) If another variable also contains the pre-modification dictionary, it will *not* see the change. This *includes* if you pass it as an argument to a command. **Tcl values are immutable.** (Or rather they behave like it when their references are shared.) ***Only* named entities like variables are mutable.**